# How to Calculate this limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}(1+\sqrt{2}+\dots+\sqrt[n]{n})$

Tags: calculus, limits

I am in college Year 1 and I am stuck with this limit:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}(1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{3}\dots+\sqrt[n]{n})$$
How should I calculate this limit containing $\sqrt[n]{n}$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$n^{1/n} \to 1$ s $n \to \infty$. By Cesaro's Theorem the given limit is also $1$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!